# How do the RealClearPolitics polling averages work?

Tags: united-states, polling

It's common for poll analysts to discuss the RCP average, and well-known that the RCP average is a simple arithmetic mean of the polls under consideration.

But what are the other rules? In particular I'm interested in:

1. What rules govern how many polls should be averaged (this seems inconsistent between various types of elections RCP is currently covering)?
2. What rules govern whether a poll will be included in the RCP average?
3. What's the minimum number of polls that needs to be available before they will publish an average?

Comment: Have you tried [asking them](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/contact.html)?

Answer (score 1):

**Not very well**

It is not clear that any "rules" apply.   Statistically their technique is on very shaky ground, see [Why is an average of an average usually incorrect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95909/why-is-an-average-of-an-average-usually-incorrect)

Their track record [really isn't anything to brag about](https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/2016/president/us/general_election_trump_vs_clinton_vs_johnson_vs_stein-5952.html).

For further information, see [Lies, damned lies, and statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lies,_damned_lies,_and_statistics).